# Permissions to print directly to USB printer

Tags: permissions, usb, devices, printing

I've a netbook with Linux. I've a usb/serial printer and I added the line `chmod 666 /dev/tty*` to `rc.local` and it prints straight after a reboot.

When I close the lid of a netbook for a while and then try to print again, it doesn't want to, until I run a command `chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0`.

How do I get this to recognize the command after hibernate without typing the command again?

Answer (score 2):

#### Group permissions

Add your username to the `lp` group would be one idea. If you take a look at the permissions and ownership of `/dev/ttyUSB0` they're most likely the user `root` being the owner, and the group being `lp`.

#### Udev

If that doesn't seem like the path you want to go, then you can override the creation/management of this device by creating/modifying a UDEV rule so that when this hardware is detected the `/dev/..` device that it manages for it can be modified as needed.

Something like this file would do it:

```
# serial
# this is the general rule that covers ttyUSB0 among others
KERNEL=="tty[A-Z]*[0-9]|pppox[0-9]*|ircomm[0-9]*|noz[0-9]*|rfcomm[0-9]*", GROUP="uucp"

# relax the permissions just for ttyUSB0
KERNEL=="ttyUSB0",              MODE="0666"
```

Look through your udev rules files, should be in a directory such as: `/etc/udev/rules.d`.

Comment: Thank you very much slm, your solution worked for me. Thanks to Jiri as well for pointing me to the right direction. I really appreciate your help guys, you rock!!!

Comment: @luclanpowr - glad this resolved your issue. Please mark this answer as accepted so that others know your issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your setup is configured correctly but you can use UDEV rules to do specific things/actions to specific device. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, I climbed on the side and nothing seems to be making sense to me there. Can I maybe just get a simple script to automatically run as soon as I open my lid so that I don't have to open a terminal and run it there

Comment: First of all I think the problem is somwhere else. Is your user in valid groups (`id' command)? If you have Ubuntu or other clicking Linux, see some GUI settings. Examine ownership on your printer device, maybe there is some group like 'lp'? If not, then you have to get idea how it works. UDev discovers new device and based on its attributes it search through rules and configures it. You should learn how it works not just copy/paste some nonsense found on internet ;)